# How to find sentence clauses that match word sequences? python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a large number of sentences from which I want to extract clauses/ segments that match certain word combinations. I have the following code that works, but it only works with one string of one word. I cannot find a way to extend it to work with multiple strings and strings of two words. I thought this was simple and asked by others before me, but could not find the answer. Can anybody help me?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')
identifiers = ('what')
sentence = df['A']

for i in sentence:
    i = i.split()
    if identifiers in i:
        index = i.index(identifiers)
        print(i[index:])
```

Give a sentence like this:

```
"Given that I want to become an entrepreneur, I am wondering what collage to attend."
```

and a list of two-word identifiers such as this:

```
identifiers = [('I am', 'I can' ..., 'I will')] # There could be dozens
```

how can I achieve a result like this?

```
I am wondering what collage to attend.
```

I tried: extending the code above, using `isin()` and something like `if any([x in i for x in identifiers])` but no solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work for multiple-word phrases because you used `split`. Since it splits on spaces (by default), logically there won't be any single element left *containing* a space.

You can use `in` immediately to test if a certain string contains any other:

```
>>> sentence = "Given that I want to become an entrepreneur, I am wondering what collage to attend."
>>> identifiers = ['I am', 'I can', 'I will']
>>> for i in identifiers:
...    if i in sentence:
...      print (sentence[sentence.index(i):])
... 
I am wondering what collage to attend.
```

Your attempt `any([x in sentence for x in identifiers])`, for these strings, shows

```
[True, False, False]
```

and while it gives *some* useful result, but still not the index, it would require another loop over this result to actually print the index. (And the `any` part is not necessary unless you specifically and only want to know *if* a sentence contains such a phrase.)

But the `[x in sentence ..]` list comprehension only yields a list of `True` and `False`, with which you cannot do anything, so it's a dead end.

But it suggests an alternative:

```
>>> [sentence.index(x) for x in identifiers if x in sentence]
[45]
```

which leads us to a *list* of results:

```
>>> [sentence[sentence.index(x):] for x in identifiers if x in sentence]
['I am wondering what collage to attend.']
```

If you add `'I want'` to your list of identifiers, you still get a correct result, now consisting of *two* sentence fragments (both all the way up to the end):

```
['I am wondering what collage to attend.', 'I want to become an entrepreneur, I am wondering what collage to attend.']
```

(For fun and while I'm at it: if you want to clip off the excess at the first comma, add a regexp that matches everything *except* a comma:

```
>>> [re.match(r'^([^,]+)', sentence[sentence.index(x):]).groups(0)[0] for x in identifiers if x in sentence]
['I am wondering what collage to attend.', 'I want to become an entrepreneur']
```

Never mind the `groups(0)[0]` part at the end of that regex, it's just to coerce the SRE_Match object back into a regular string.)

Comment: Thanks a lot more your impressive answer! When I try your code, with a single sentence it works. But what I try it on my dataframe sentence = df['A'] it does not. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @twhale: the `sentence` you get, is that a regular string? I'm not too familiar with Pandas, and there is no example CSV in your question. (Which, mind you, it does not seem to need anyway.) You'll need to find out how to feed your dataset one string at a time into my code.

Comment: I am not exactly sure. CVS sometimes changes the data structure. I assume it consists of a column with strings in each cell. But it is possible that each string is contained in a list, so that every cell of the column contains a list that contains a string. I will have to figure that out.